# OutOfRangeException error when the array has items in it?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, xna

I have 3 classes and they more or less go like this:

**Class a**

```
class a {
    b bObject;
    public a() {

    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
        bObject = new b(); // I know this is bad but I need this here
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        b.DrawFunction();
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```

**Class b**

```
class b {
    List<c> cList = new List<c>();
    int itemAtIndex10;
    public b() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            cList.Add(new c { bunch of variables here }); // 32 items in the list
        }
    }
    public void DrawFunction() {
        spriteBatch.Draw(drawstuff);

        // more code

        itemAtIndex10 = cList[10].variable; // This causes an OutOfRangeException?
    }
}
```

**Class c**

```
class c {
    // Loads of variables here
    public c() {

    }
}
```

Why does this cause an OutOfRangeException? The error is telling me it's coming from "cList" even though in class b, I've added 32 items.

Comment: Obviously, by the time you try to access `[10]`, there is no `[10]`. Have you used the debugger to look at this?

Comment: @Hayden Perry Do your realy have the keyword class in your constructor?

Comment: I said below that was a typo, woops... I've edited it. I know for certain that what everyone has been saying is not the problem. :p Besides, surely it's obvious that was a typo if I knew I was getting OutOfRangeException instead of a compile error?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
public class b() {
```

to

```
public b() {
```

As what you're doing currently is creating a second class called b within your b class, rather than creating a constructor for b.

That said - I have no idea how you managed to get

```
cList.Add(new cList { bunch of variables here });
```

to even compile.

Comment: public class b() { is also impossible to compile

Comment: Very true. Looking at it again - I suspect that the class keyword must have been accidentally added in when the example was typed out - so my suggestion isn't going to help. Apologies.

Comment: Another typo with cList.Add... I'm on fire today :p

Answer (score -1):

I think this line...

```
cList.Add(new cList { bunch of variables here }); // 32 items in the
```

Should be this line...

```
cList.Add(new c { bunch of variables here }); // 32 items in the
```

unless i'm mistaken cList is a List, where c is the class c from below.

Comment: Yeah, but he references `[10]`, so that doesn't matter.

Comment: That was a typo... I've fixed it now. My code is long and complicated so I thought I would retype it out in a simpler way but obviously that was probably a bad idea considering the typos :p

Answer (score -1):

> cList.Add(new cList { bunch of variables here });

Looks like cList has 1 element cList. So acess should be like

> var x = cList[0]

and then

> itemAtIndex10 = x[10]

Edit : My bad, did not spotted this is loop. I will not delete it, but it is correct answer, sorry :/

Comment: The OP clearly says he adds 32 items, as you can see.